# ¿Cómo agregar Tinymce a un template?

Tags: python, django, tinymce

Mi pregunta formulada es la siguiente necesito agregar TinyMCE en mi proyecto de Django para darle un estilo a mi template.

Pero no logro poder mostrar en el template HTML, ¿cuáles serían las configuraciones dentro de mi proyecto para poder mostrarlo correctamente?

1. Dentro de mi modelo especifiqué esta línea:

   ```
   from tinymce import models as tinymce_models

   body = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
   ```
2. De hecho la libreria la instalé con `pip install django-tinymce` y realicé los pasos de la documentación.
3. Lo que yo pretendo es otorgar formato a mi template con esta librería.
   Lo estoy realizando de la siguiente manera dentro de mi template HTML.

   ```
   {{ post.body }}
   ```
4. El resultado es:

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Me podrían indicar que proceso estoy realizando mal?

Answer (score 2):

Por seguridad, cuando se usa código HTML al presentar una plantilla en Django, se *escapa* para evitar problemas de seguridad.

En este caso específico para mostrar el texto, deberías usar el filtro `safe` indicado en la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) de Django.

#### Advertencia

Sin embargo, debes tomar en cuenta que el paquete `django-tinymce` se usa en **formularios**, por lo tanto, **deberías usar un *widget* tipo `Textarea`** para que el *editor* pueda mostrar los controles o bien **usar el modo [*Inline* de TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/inline/)**.